# How to limit the maximum network speed in the whole Virtual Host?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, rate-limiting

### Background

I have a Apache (with NginX Reverse Proxy) as web server. I have a forum and a image host service running.

But as you know, image host service causes a lot of network bandwidth (Mbps). I want to reserve some of the bandwidth to my forum by limiting the maximum traffic  in the virtual host of the image host service.

### What I have done:

### Apache

I have installed the **mod_bw** module in order to limit the maximum bandwidth. It seems working very well because it slows down the page loading. But this is not enough. I need to limit the download speed also and now the image will download at full speed. So this one is not working (or partly working) but I will keep it in the **httpd.conf**.

### Nginx

Built-in module **limit_rate** is working for downloading image. So it looks like if combining two modules, the image host service can run at a restricted environment. But wait a minute ... When I download multiple images at once, all images will download at the same limited speed. For example I set to 50KB/s, if I download an image, the maximum speed is 50KB/s. And then I download another image file before the last one completed, the download speed of both images are 50KB/s, in total is 100KB/s.

This is not what I need.

### What I actually need is:

No matter how many concurrent users are browsing the image host web page at the same time, they can only share the total bandwidth that set to 50KB/s. (Just an example, I will increase this)

As I have both Apache and NginX, I don't care combining multiple modules to help me to reach the objective. Please help me to solve the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: You nginx concerns regarding `limit_rate` are already [**noted and addressed** in the manual](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/#limit_rate)... - Also consider that a fairly typical approach for hosting images/static content  is to **"make it somebody else's problem"** and either off-load it to a CDN or to a separate server (rather than a name based virtual host) . On a dedicated host bandwidth usage doesn't impact your other services and there you're not limited to traffic shaping at the application level but can also do it from the IP stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set a limit to the connections, you should be able to do it with **limit_zone** and **limit_conn** directives. Example:

Inside your server block configuration:

```
limit_rate 128K; limit_zone one $binary_remote_addr 10m;
```

Inside your location block configuration:

```
limit_conn one 10;
```

In this example, it would allow 10 connections per IP with 1 Mbit each.